# WPF - unselect underline or strikethrough in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, richtextbox

If I set a button for a TextElement property switching on and off works well - either for the selected text or just to toggle on or off as typing text, as per this example.

```
 Private Sub TextEditor_SwitchItalics(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim vEditor As RichTextBox = TextEditorGrid.FindName("Controls_TextEditorRTF")
        With vEditor
            Select Case vEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty)
                Case FontStyles.Normal
                    vEditor.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Italic)
                Case FontStyles.Italic
                    vEditor.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Normal)

            End Select
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

With TextDecorations I am having a problem - I can switch on, and can switch off selected text but attempting to unselect as typing has no effect. Any idea on how I can resolve this? Thanks

```
Private Sub TextEditor_SwitchStrikethrough(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim vEditor As RichTextBox = TextEditorGrid.FindName("Controls_TextEditorRTF")
        Dim SelectionRange As New TextRange(vEditor.Selection.Start, vEditor.Selection.End)
        If (SelectionRange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty).Equals(TextDecorations.Strikethrough)) Then
            For Each Item In TextDecorations.Strikethrough
                vEditor.Selection.ClearAllProperties()
            Next
        Else
            vEditor.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Strikethrough)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that ClearAllProperties has no effect, but setting TextDecorations to Nothing works

```
Private Sub TextEditor_SwitchStrikethrough(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim vEditor As RichTextBox = TextEditorGrid.FindName("Controls_TextEditorRTF")
        Dim SelectionRange As New TextRange(vEditor.CaretPosition, vEditor.CaretPosition)
        If (SelectionRange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty).Equals(TextDecorations.Strikethrough)) Then
            For Each Item In TextDecorations.Strikethrough
                vEditor.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, Nothing)
                'vEditor.Selection.ClearAllProperties()
            Next
        Else
            vEditor.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Strikethrough)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```